# Android webview onTouch() don't working right

Tags: android, android-webview

My code:

```
final WebView webView1 = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.example);

        webView1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {  
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Ads.this, General.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
                return false;
            }
        });
        webView1.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView1.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        StringBuilder htmlData = new StringBuilder("<html>"); 
        htmlData.append("<head></head>");
        htmlData.append("<body style='margin:0;padding:0;'>"); 
        htmlData.append("banner from my websive with link"); 
        htmlData.append("</body>"); 
        htmlData.append("</html>"); 
        webView1.loadData(htmlData.toString(),"text/html", "ISO 8859-1");
```

Please, where I have a problem?

How I start first Intent and after browserver window?

PS: I don't know why but if I click on webview, intent will start 5 times in same time.

Answer (score 0):

Try use this code

```
webView1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {  
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                Intent intent = new Intent(Ads.this, General.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
              }  
              return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: ERR: Incompatible operand types MotionEvent and int

Comment: huh, one problem is solved, intent starting 1 times. But now, browserver window don't open ever.